# remove duplication in object array from firebase or filter it? look code for more info

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

Here I validate if my users status is true, and if they are, I put them in an array. The thing here is that next time it will validate, all those who  already was true will  be added to the same array. Can it be solved by filter instead of push, or should I take the validation in any other way?

```
import {
  UPDATE_LIST_SUCCESS
} from './types'

var arr = []
export const fetchList = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
   firebaseRef.database().ref().child('users')
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
        var data = child.val()
        if (child.val().profile.status === true) {
          arr.push(data)
        }
      })
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: arr })
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Yes you could use `.filter`, just change `.forEach` to `.filter` and return `child.val().profile.status === true` and save the result of that in `arr`. But you could also just move `var arr = []` into the `fetchList` function

Comment: like so ?  snapshot.filter(child => child.val().status === true ). Filter is not a method is the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import {
  UPDATE_LIST_SUCCESS
} from './types'


export const fetchList = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
   firebaseRef.database().ref().child('users')
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      var arr = snapshot.filter(function (child) {
          return child.val().profile.status === true
      }).map(function (child) {
          return child.val();
      });
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: arr })
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you man for taking the time ! Still dosen´t work cause snapshot is an object..

Answer (score 0):

So here is my not so pretty way of solving it, but it works.

```
import {firebaseRef} from '../firebase/firebase'

import {
UPDATE_LIST_SUCCESS
  } from './types'

export const fetchList = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
const arrayToFilter = []

firebaseRef.database().ref().child('users')
.on('value', snapshot => {
  let snap = snapshot.val()

  // Get acces to the keys in the object i got from firebase
  let keys = Object.keys(snap)

  //  iterate the keys and put them in an User object
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let k = keys[i]
    let name = snap[k].profile.name
    let age = snap[k].profile.age
    let status = snap[k].profile.status
    let profile_picture = snap[k].profile.profile_picture

    let users = {name: '', age: '', status: Boolean, profile_picture: ''}

    users.name = name
    users.age = age
    users.status = status
    users.profile_picture = profile_picture
    // adding the user object to an array
    arrayToFilter.push(users)
  }
  // filter and creates a new array with users depending if their status is true
  let arr = arrayToFilter.filter(child => child.status === true)

  dispatch({ type: UPDATE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: arr })
  })
}
}
```